# How can I model a dictionary of an array in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, data-modeling

I am fairly new to CoreData but I have been searching for a solution to my problem for quite some time and not really finding an answer. I am hoping someone can help me with my solution. I have an app that I am building. It is a recipe and meal plan app, and I am stuck on the meal plan part. I have a calendar a user can select the date and I can extract that date. But the problem lies in the fact that the user selects a date and chooses a meal for breakfast, Lunch, dinner, and snacks. I have all that set up but I am trying to figure out how I can model that data so I can save it so it can be accessed later. I created a separate entity to hold the selections. So it creates a dictionary with the key as the date and the selected recipes as the value? However I run into all kinds of issues with trying to save my data like that. I was curious if anyone had any suggestions. I would show some code. But the issue for me is logic and I am not sure how I should proceed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't think in terms of persisting a dictionary in Core Data, instead you should use relationships between your entities. A selection has a date attribute (and some type attribute) and a relationship (also an attribute) to a meal/recipe

Comment: Thanks for responding. This definitely helped me with my perspective.